# How to represent and navigate this kind of data?

Tags: python, graph

I am working with a list of small functions and want to memorize and "navigate" them. All the functions are treated like black boxes and have got at least one argument and at least one output. An example of those functions is the following:

```
A -> f1() -> B
C -> f2() -> D
B -> f3() -> E
F -> f4() -> D
A,D -> f5() -> G
H -> f6() -> C,F
```

After inserting the characteristics of those functions in the program i want to be able to ask the software "Can i obtain E given A?" and receive the answer "Yes applying **f1()** and then **f3()**" or "You can't obtain that with this input".

I thought about creating a graph where the nodes are the input/output (A,B,C,D,E....) and the edges are the functions and then try to find a path between input and desidered output. This works if a function takes only one input and return only one output.

I am working in Python so a solution in this language is preferred.

Summary: **How can i store the functions in the example in a way that allows me to find if given some inputs I can obtain some outputs?**

Feel free to edit to improve readability if you think is necessary.

Comment: If your question is answered please mark it as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your objective is definitely a Graph problem. However, be aware that if you allow your graph to go deeper: A -> f1() -> B -> f3() -> E for instance, the combinatory can become quickly very large. There is no simple solution.

In short you have to create a graph, and then explore the graph looking for a path from x1 to x2. Maybe you can have a look to graphDB such as Neo4J or GraphDB. Maybe the python lib NetworkX will be able to do the job too.

Comment: Looks interesting, but I still have the problem of describing functions with multiple inputs or multiple outputs

Comment: My comments works for this situation. Just have a look to graph libraries or graphDB. It is no simple problem and you won't get any answer here, too much complex to be explained on a forum.
Please close your question if you have your answer.